# Display compressed Image data in Unity scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d, unity3d-2dtools

I want to display a series of compressed image data in a Unity scene. I am receiving this continuous stream of compressed image data from [ROS2](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CompressedImage.html). For reference the RGB bitmap [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClBhH.png) :

> array('B', [255, 216, 0, 1, 1, 216 ...)

The image format is rgb8; jpeg compressed bgr8.

I want to display these images (video frames) on a small portion of the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vrpl.jpg).

Since I am fairly new to unity and still learning it please excuse this beginner-level question. So far I found the `texture2D.LoadImage(imageData);` to be useful.

Any inputs as to how to approach the problem would be really useful.

Sorry if there is a lot of redundant information here.